# overriding one of 2 overloaded heritated methods c++

Tags: c++

This is the problem

I have to maintain and improve a code of this style

```
class Base {

    virtual char *getname() {return NULL}

    virtual char *getname(int i);

}

class Child1 : public base {

    virtual char *getname() { //its own treatment */

    virtual char *getname(int i) { / its treatment */

}

class Child2 : public base {

    virtual char *getname() { //its own treatment */

    virtual char *getname(int i) { / its treatment */

}
```

The code like this works.

I found a way to have a generic `getname(int i)` that works for all children, so I did that

```
class Base {

    virtual char *getname() {return NULL}

    virtual char *getname(int i) {the new generic code};

}

class Child1 : public base {

    virtual char *getname() { //its own treatment */

    /*virtual char *getname(int i) {*/

}

class Child2 : public base {

    virtual char *getname() { //its own treatment */

    /*virtual char *getname(int i) */

}
```

The problem I had is the methods hiding.

The overriding of `getname()` hides the `getname(int i)` of the base class.

In the base class we have to maintain the 2 methods with these names for compatibility.

The solution of using `base::getname`, I think we can't use it here, because it can be used when we have only one version of `getname` in base class, but here we have two.

Have you an idea how to add my generic code which works for all `getname(int i)` without breaking the actual comportment?

Comment: `using base::getname` will work : it imports all the overloads from the base class and adds them to the child's overload set.

Comment: Did you tried to make the `getname(int i)` of your base class a not virtual function ? Overload should not be possible then.

Comment: no even if it's a non virtual, we can overlad it , but it will not be a _dynamic_ _polymorphism_

Comment: @Quentin i'm building with the **using** directive and i will tell you the result

Comment: Yes , using base::getname resolves the problem. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a manifestation of the hiding rule.  By declaring one of the `getname()` functions in a derived class, all other variants are hidden.

The usual solution is to add `using Base::getname()` in the definition of each derived class that only overrides one of the inherited forms of `getname()`.

Alternatively, simply give the different variants of the function distinct names.